# file descriptors, difference between printf and std::cout

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
//#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(){
int stdout = dup(1);
char p[] = "test.txt";
close(1);
int output = open(p, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
//std::cout << "lala" << endl;
printf("lala\n");
close(output);

dup(stdout);
close(stdout);
printf("lolo\n");
//  std::cout << "lolo" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I think that printf and std::cout have to output the same thing, I want "lala" on the file, and "lolo" on the terminal screen, why this version (with prinf) print everything on screen and the version with "std::cout" print the things as I like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the internal buffering of the `stdio` library. `"lala\n"` is too small to be flushed to the stream straight away, so it is kept in `printf` internal buffer until it is flushed later.

If you add an `fflush` then you get the desired result:

```
int main(){
    int stdout_fd = dup(1);
    char p[] = "test.txt";
    close(1);
    int output = open(p, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    //std::cout << "lala" << endl;
    printf("lala\n");
    fflush(stdout); // flush the internal buffer
    close(output); // fclose would flush too

    dup(stdout_fd);
    close(stdout_fd);
    printf("lolo\n");
    //  std::cout << "lolo" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also I have renamed your local variable `stdout` because that is a globally defined one by `stdio`. Also `stdin` and `stderr` are `FILE *` pointing to the stdio control streams for those.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of redirecting streams is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/